# Prove that there exists an $n\in\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{-\infty,+\infty\right\}$ such that... (Dynamics)

Tags: proof-verification, dynamical-systems

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and on it the following dynamics described by $T\colon X\to X$ as follows: A 1 becomes a 2, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if at least one of its two neighbors is 1.

Moreover, consider
$$
Y=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n(X).
$$

**Statement to prove:**

$\eta\in X$ is in $Y$ if and only if there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{-\infty,\infty\right\}$, such that:

- *Condition I*: At $n$ and to the left on $n$, every 1 has a 2 to its left, every 2 has a 0 to its left, and every 0 has a 0 or a 1 to its left.
- *Condition II*: To the the right of $n$, every 1 has a 2 to its right, every 2 has a 0 to its right and every 0 has a 0 or a 1 to its right.

---

**Here is what I tried.** Please, have a look on it and tell me, if it is okay or not.

*Proof*

"$\Longleftarrow$": Let $\eta\in X$ with a corresponding $n$ fulfilling the conditions of the statement. By the following procedure, one can see that $\eta\in Y$: First develop the positions n and n+1 back infinitely often, a 1 getting a 0, a 2 getting a 1 and a 0 remaining a 0.

Then for each step back of the positions left to $n$ and right to $n+1$, just make the left-shift and right-shift, respectively.

*Example*: Let | separate the $n$-th from the $(n+1)$-th position.

$$
10021|2001
$$

*Step 1:*
$$
10021|2001\\
    0|1   \\
    0|0   \\
    0|0   \\
    \text{etc.}
$$

*Step 2:* Fill the other gaps by left-shift and right-shift, respectively:
$$
\ldots 10021|2001\ldots\\
00210|1200\\
02100|0120\\
21000|0012\\
\text{etc.}
$$

This shows that $\eta\in Y$.

"$\Longrightarrow$": Let $\eta\in Y$. By $\eta(x)$ denote the position $x$ of $\eta$.

W.l.o.g. let $\eta(x)=1$. In particular, $\eta\in T(X)$. There are the following possible left and right neighbours of $\eta(x)=1$ (where $\eta(x)=1$ is supposed to stand in the middle):

- 012
- 212
- 210
- 112
- 211

Take *Case 1:* 012 exemplarily-

When we develop $012$ one step back, we have two possibilities (that is, we have at least two pre-images) to do so:
$$
012\\
201
$$
or
$$
012\\
001
$$
Choose the first possibility. Then, when we develop this backwards, one gets the following scheme:
$$
\ldots\star 0120\star\ldots\\
\ldots\star 020120\star\ldots\\
\ldots\star 02100120\star\ldots\\
\ldots\star 0210\star\star 0120\star\ldots\\
\ldots\star 0210\star\star\star 0120\star\ldots\\
\text{etc.}
$$
Choose the $\star$'s within the "pyramide" all to be $0$.

For the $\star$'s on the left, if we choose one of it to be a $1$ then all of it have to be $1$. If we choose one of it to be a $0$, then all of it have to be $0$'s. Left of the stars on the left, there $1$'s ,$2$'s and $0$'s can only appear as *Condition I*  from the statement says.

The same holds for the $\star$'s on the right. If we choose one of it to be a $1$, all are $1$'s. And if we choose one of it to be a $0$, all are $0$'s. To the right of the $\star$'s on the right side, there $1$'s, $2$'s, and $0$'s can only appear as *Condition II* from the statement wants them to appear.

*So in this case, we can choose the $n$ to be $x$.*

The other cases work similarly. Namely, in case that we start with the neighbourhood $112$ (again $\eta(x)=1$ in the middle), we can choose $n$ to be $x-1$. For the other cases we can chose $n=x$, too, as in case 1.

(*Remark*: Starting with $\eta(x)=1$ as done above is w.l.o.g. because if we start with a $2$, there is a $1$ in the row before and we can choose the $n$ as in the corresponding case starting with a neighbourhood of 1 because developing forward does not change the desired order of $0$'s, $1$'s and $2$'s as *Condition I* and *Condition II* wants them to appear. If we start with a $0$ then either we always have a $0$ before each $0$ and we can choose $n$ to be any number in $\mathbb{Z}$, or at some time there is a $2$ before a $0$ and then a $1$ before this $2$ and we can again choose the $n$ as in the corresponding neighborhoud of $1$.)

Finally, if we have a $y\in Y$ consisting of $0$'s, $1$'s and $2$' such that there is a $2$ on the right (left) of every 1, a $0$ on the right (left) of every $2$ and a $0$ or a $1$ on the right (left) of every $0$, we can choose $n=+\infty$ and $n=-\infty$, respectively.

$\Box$

---

I really hope to get a feedback from you, because I do need this statement in a project and thus I really need a proof. I gave you my proof and hope to get an answer back from you. Thank you very much!

Best wishes

math12

Comment: Is this a hypothesis of your own, or is this something you've been given to prove?

Comment: It is not my own hypothesis, it is given.

Comment: Its just that it seems to have some problems. Imagine, for instance, that $x=\{x_i\}$ is such that at indexes 10 and 11, you put a 2 and a 1, then at 100 and 101, you put a 1 and a 2, then at 1000 a 21, at 10000 a 12 etc. and every other entry is a 0. Then, for any n, there are going to be an infinite number of 12s in $T^n x$ and an infinite number of 21s. Certainly, as n increases, you'll occasionally get an annihilation of a 12 and a 21, but there'll always be more left.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting a 2 at index 10" for example?

Comment: Well, $X$ is the set of all bi-infinite strings of 0s, 1s, and 2s. By "putting a 2 at index 10", I mean that $x_{10} = 2$. So, the $x$ I'm describing has an initial infinite sequence of 0s, and then $\ldots, 0, 2, 1, 0, \ldots, 0, 1,  2, 0, \ldots,  0, 2, 1, 0, \ldots, 0, 1,  2, 0, \ldots,  $ where the intervening strings of 0s are getting larger and larger.

Comment: But where exactly is the problem? This sequence is in $Y$, right?  And when developing it back, there is no such n?

Comment: No matter what $n$ you choose, at least half of the numbers on the right of $n$ fail condition II. I cannot see how it could be an element of $Y$.

Comment: But when it is no element of Y, there is no problem! Because it is stated that only for elements in Y there is such an n.

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong, my apologies.

Comment: Ok, but now I do not see why it is not in Y. Hehe :D

Comment: Its not in Y because if you got back... I think about 450 steps, you have $\ldots, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, \ldots $ which must have been $\ldots, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, \ldots$ which doesn't have an ancestor. Y is the set that has infinitely many ancestors.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Now i see.

Comment: Did you have a look on the proof?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the following helps. It is just about the workings of $T$, and there are no limit considerations. I did a few simulations with  random starting sequences over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$. What I observed is that after only two forward $T$-steps there are just the following features left: In a soup of zeros there are little trains 12 moving to the left one unit per step and little trains 21 moving to the right one unit per step. When two such trains collide they annihilate each other within two steps. The following figure shows an example. Zeros are not printed, ones are replaced by red bullets, and  twos by black bullets. I venture that staring at this figure will lead to the solution of your problem.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can have a look on my added proof. Anyway, thank you for your efforts.